# A delete and undelete queue

Tags: feature-request, review

I would like to request that a review queue be added to [Review](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review) that can deal with delete and undelete votes.  Adding such a queue will help members of the community help manage, just like the close and reopen queues help.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "a queue for flags"?  Moderators _do_ have a queue for dealing with those, so I think it's already implemented.

Comment: Also, could you add a tag or two in addition to [meta-tag:feature-request]?  Perhaps [meta-tag:review]?

Comment: @JonEricson I edited the request.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113397/add-a-delete-tab-to-the-review-section

Comment: Ok.  The queue for flags is a pretty radical change in the way moderation works on Stack Exchange.  The delete and undelete queues are a more conventional idea.  If I were you, I'd pick the idea that's most important to you and focus on that.  I'd also put in some effort to explain why the queue would be necessary and how the community as a whole would benefit.  Ideally, you could pull up some examples where the feature would have solved a problem.  As it is, this suggestion is not likely to be taken seriously.